# Where is the description of my exception in Google Mobile App Analytics v2?

Tags: android, mobile, google-analytics

I use Google Mobile App Analytics v2 in my application.

I created my own ExceptionParser to have a better description.

```
@Override
public String getDescription(String threadName, Throwable t) {
    StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Header
    messageBuilder.append(getHeader());

    // Message
    messageBuilder.append("Message \n\n");
    messageBuilder.append(t.getMessage());
    messageBuilder.append("\n\n");

    // Stack trace
    messageBuilder.append("Stacktrace \n\n");
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = t.getStackTrace();
    for (int i = 0; i < stackTraceElements.length; i++) {
        StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = stackTraceElements[i];
        messageBuilder.append(stackTraceElement.getClassName());
        messageBuilder.append(".");
        messageBuilder.append(stackTraceElement.getMethodName());
        messageBuilder.append("(");
        messageBuilder.append(stackTraceElement.getFileName());
        messageBuilder.append(":");
        messageBuilder.append(stackTraceElement.getLineNumber());
        messageBuilder.append(")\n");
    }
    messageBuilder.append("\n");

    // Thread
    messageBuilder.append("Thread \n\n");
    messageBuilder.append(threadName);

    String message = messageBuilder.toString();
    try {
        MyApplication.getFileLogger().e(message);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Log.e(TAG,"Exception: " + e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    return message;
```

Where I can see this description in analytics console ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions

According to:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events

```
trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value)
```

> category (required) The name you supply for the group of objects you
>   want to track.
>
> label (optional) An optional string to provide additional dimensions
>   to the event data.

And then:

> View the reports. Once event tracking has been set up and working on
>   your site for a day, go to the Content section of the reports and view
>   Event Tracking.

Catgory should be an Exception I guess, and you could provide your information in the label parameter.

I don't know the maximal length alloweb, but should be enough..

```
  EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(
       "Crash",  // Category
       "WatheverYouWant",  // Action
       getDescription(thread,e), // Label
       0);       // Value
```